# @font-face on local IP only displaying in chrome

Tags: css, .htaccess, cross-browser, localhost, font-face

I want my friend to able to check out my WIP site that I've been developing locally using Chrome (localhost/sitename/, or now actually myIP/sitename). I got it to work and realized my fonts weren't loading, and then checked all my other browsers on my computer and noticed the same thing.

I've done absolute paths and even tried adding [permissions](http://www.wpexplorer.org/knowledgebase/font-face-permissions-via-htaccess/) to the .htaccess file to no avail. Below is my code. Any suggestions? Nothing is live yet.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'arvo';
    src: url('/arvo-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/arvo-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/arvo-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/arvo-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/arvo-regular-webfont.svg#arvo') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: What local server environment do you have? A path like `/arvo-regular-webfont.eot` (with the slash at the front) may or may not work, depending on your setup.

Comment: 1) your fonts path should be relative to css file and not markup html file can you check that once 2) also on http://www.font2web.com/ this tool if you browse font then it gives you ready made zip with paths and font folder which you can setup on localhost and debug issue

Comment: @ralph.m - I'm using WampServer

Comment: @PravinVaichal I've tried "/wp-content/themes/theme-name/fonts/font-name" and that hasn't worked either

Comment: What happens if you click on the link to the font file within dev tools? Is the path correct? On a local server, your root file may not be where you expect.

Comment: can you provide URL of working environment will be helpful to dubug

Comment: @ralph.m EDIT- I figured it out, thanks for helping me debug guys; I realized I didn't include the full relative path.